# no-op exporter for metrics in open telemetry collector

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I have a service that generates otel data (traces and metrics). When the service is deployed to prod env, the traces and metrics are exported to DataDog. However, for local testing (specifically traces), I am running otel collector (latest image) and that is exporting the traces over to jaeger (also running locally). Both the collector and jaeger are running in docker. I do not want prometheus to export metrics because I dont need to test the metrics part. So I wanted to drop the metrics from being exported in the otel colelctor. I looked for a no-op processor or a no-op exporter but cant seem to find one. I tried completely ignoring (not defining) metrics section in the pipelines portion of the otel collector config file. After I did that, my service is throwing errors that it cant export metrics. So really the only option seems to be not sending metrics as part of telemetry data from the service itself but I dont want to change that since its the same code that goes to prod.

What are my options?

Tried the following:

- ignored the metrics section in pipelines in collector config file

Answer (score 1):

There is a [filter process in contrib](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/filterprocessor). From the README, it can:

> The filterprocessor allows dropping spans, span events, metrics, datapoints, and logs from the collector.

You could add a filter that matches all metric names, causing all metrics to be dropped before being exported:

```yaml
processors:
  filter/ottl:
    error_mode: ignore
    metrics:
      metric:
          - 'IsMatch(name, "*")'
```

Comment: How does the filter processor help drop all metrics? At the end of the day, I dont want to have a metrics exporter because I dont have a destination for them. But I cant stop the metrics source (because the service is producing otel metrics). The metrics are reaching the otel collector but I want to suppress them at the collector level.

Comment: I added some more info to my answer - by adding the filter processor and matching on ALL metrics, all metrics will be dropped and never hit the exporter. You'd still have to configure a dummy exporter, but it should never be hit if the filter is in place.

Comment: Great thanks. I will give that a try. For now, I ended up adding a Logger as an exporter that is logging to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`debug`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/exporter/debugexporter/README.md) exporter, with right config, e.g.

```yaml
receivers:
  ...

processors:
  ...

exporters:
  ...
  debug/noop:
    verbosity: normal
    sampling_initial: 0
    sampling_thereafter: 0

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [memory_limiter, batch]
      exporters: [debug/noop]
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [memory_limiter, batch]
      exporters: [otlp]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [memory_limiter, batch]
      exporters: [otlp]
```

BTW: there is [nop exporter](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/exporter/exportertest/nop_exporter.go), but IMHO it is used only for a testing